# Can I create a group of dynamically added recipients, based on a datasheet?

Tags: email, groups, datasheet

I want my intranet users to send email to a distribution group. Not so strange so far, just a regular send list.

But instead of a classic list with individually added recipients, they should be fetched from a datasheet within a specific sharepointpage. That datasheet contain a few criterias and an emailadress field.

Is this possible?

The same but other way to describe; "send my email to all emailadresses in this list, which have this criteria "send to all which have x == true". But for simplicity we must be able to send to a groupname.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to go through whole list.
I would create two workflows, one to send emails and the other to trigger the first one. So Email workflow would work on Item created and the other one The trigger would do on Item update.
For first workflow:
Create list with columns User name/full name, column eMail that will be people picker (but choose work email from drop down menu) and column yes/no or choose with Yes/No options Send eMail.
After this, create workflow and put if clause when column Send eMail is Yes than send email.

For second workflow:
Create column however you want, and put number column. This workflow should just do something in the background like calculation, +1 adding on that column whenever it is updated. Just hide that column from content and from view as this should be background job.

I think you can also do this with workflow 2013 with an option foreach, but I didn't work with this one yet so I cannot explain or describe what and how to do it with foreach.

Comment: just a note: this will work good for smaller group of items. if you will have 100+ users to send emails than I do not recommend it.